# when ı run truffle migrate using truffle ı got this error

Tags: truffle, ganache, general-network-error

when ı run truffle migrate ı got this error

> Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://127.0.0.1:8545. Check your network configuration.
> CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:8545.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Unm.png)

```
npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g ganache-cli --force
rm package-lock.json
sudo npm install -g ganache-cli
```

also ı changed truffle-caonfig.json file

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
     test: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution after an hour.

Solution: Ensure Ganache is Running: Make sure that Ganache is running and the local blockchain is active. If you closed the terminal where Ganache was running, start Ganache again by running the ganache command in a new terminal. then use commands on another terminal it will resolve the issue.